# Can the order of items in Google Drive sidebar be changed

Tags: google-drive

I'd like to change the order of the items listed in the Google Drive sidebar - I often access starred items and would like that to come right after Google Drive (in the default location of Computers). Is there a way to do this?

So far my experimenting and searching have been fruitless.

Answer (score 2):

No. The company wants their product to be simple, so customizations like this are not offered.